turbo_stream_from -> active job -> broadcast race condition?
I am trying to implement a Turbo Stream that updates the DOM over a socket. I have the following setup:
In my view:
<%= turbo_stream_from "connections_notifications" %>

In the controller, I trigger a job:
PrepSidenavJob.perform_later(current_user)

The job broadcasts a Turbo Stream:
Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_replace_to(
  "connections_notifications",
  target: "connections_notification",
  partial: 'product/sidenav_badge',
  locals: {count: connections_notification},
  layout: nil
)

I'm encountering a race condition with the following event order:

Render first template
Drop job
Job processes
Job broadcasts
Client connects to /cable
Client receives nothing

The job executes so quickly that the broadcast happens before the client connects to the websocket, causing the client to miss the update.
I'm using the following versions:

Rails 7.2
@hotwired/turbo-rails 8.0.12

Any insights into why this setup isn't working as expected would be appreciated.

eh, I think this is just https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/52420

i'm not really following your steps, how are you triggering a job before the page loads, is the job already running? in my mind, you load the page, you subscribe, click a button, the job runs, you get updates. but you should be subscribed ahead of time. you could delay the job by a few seconds or run it synchronously if it's that fast, or you could use a remote turbo_frame to load "product/_sidenav_badge" after the page is loaded, or have a custom channel that stays subscribed all the time, or broadcast twice with a small delay.

@Alex: In the question the job is triggered by the initial load of the page.

I am currently facing the same issue and think the basic setup we are using is not correct. ActionCable/TurboStreams assumes that you would have a /cable connection before you submit the job.

Visit page and connect to /cable
Submit form via Turbo (no page reload)
Controller returns Turbo replacement for form and starts background job
Background job broadcasts update to replace

Another solution might be trigger an initial update when a new connection happens on the server. This could be done with: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Callbacks.html I believe it could be done with after_subscribe :send_update..., unless: :subscription_rejected?
Lots and lots of people have the same issue it seems by the way:

https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/498#issuecomment-2125057060 => Use callbacks https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/1ec08jp/how_do_i_solve_race_when_connecting_turbo/ => Use on_connect on the ActionCable::Channel
https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/avoiding-a-race-condition-on-initial-subscription-in-turbo-rails/5761/2 => Resend after a couple of seconds
https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/lttk0l/turbo_streams_how_to_properly_structure_logic_for/
https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/turbo-stream-broadcasts-happening-before-turbo-stream-from-can-establish-websocket-connection-in-system-tests-with-capybara/3710 => Same issue but during testing


basic setup is fine.  drop the job in your Channel#subscribe.  ends up working fine.

I am still starting the job in the controller, but in the Channel#subscribe I resend the object if the job has already completed.
